# Facebook registration and whitelists

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook, registration

I am using the registration plugin. My website will be in private beta so I check the user email address against a white list.
How can I tell facebook that the registration failed?

Also, How do I unlink a user? Since it failed, the user can't re-register right now because facebook thinks he's already a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration plugin includes several advanced features like being able to validate the form data. Using this you could check to see if the email address is in your whitelist before the user actually connects

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/#async

Comment: Yes I think this is the right approach. Although form.email returns undefined ...

Answer (score 1):

You can authorize the user from facebook after the complete securities and once user is completely verified then make facebook account for user.

Answer (score 0):

The old method was to use [auth.revokeAuthorization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeAuthorization/) and it has **not** been replicated in the Graph API.  Using Graph, you could try a combination of [banning the user and then immediately unbanning](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/).  Alternatively, you could put your calls to Facebook in a callback function that only fires on a successful registration against your whitelist.